# RSPEC test Get/NEW custom STI routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes, single-table-inheritance

I have a Page class with a StaticPage subclass.

I want to test that I can access a route for new static pages in RSPEC.

routes:

```
resources :sites do
      resources :pages, only: [:index, :destroy]
      resources :static_pages, except: :show, controller: "pages", type: "StaticPage"
```

spec:

```
describe 'GET :new' do
    it 'assigns @page' do
      expect(@page).to_not be_nil
    end
  end
```

fails

How do I test GET :new

```
new_organization_site_static_page GET    /organizations/:organization_id/sites/:site_id/static_pages/new(.:format)      pages#new {:type=>"StaticPage"}
```

in RSPEC.